# find: -exec vs xargs (aka Why does "find | xargs basename" break?)

Tags: command-line, find, gnu, xargs

I was trying to find all files of a certain type spread out in subdirectories, and for my purposes I only needed the filename.  I tried stripping out the path component via `basename`, but it did't work with `xargs`:

```
$ find . -name '*.deb' -print | xargs basename 
basename: extra operand `./pool/main/a/aalib/libaa1_1.4p5-37+b1_i386.deb'
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

I get the same thing (exactly the same error) with either of these variations:

```
$ find . -name '*.deb' -print0 | xargs -0 basename 
$ find . -name '*.deb' -print | xargs basename {}
```

This, on the other hand, works as expected:

```
$ find . -name '*.deb' -exec basename {} \;
foo
bar
baz
```

This happens on up-to-date Cygwin and Debian 5.0.3.  My diagnosis is that xargs is for some reason passing two input lines to basename, but why?  What's going on here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because `basename` wants just one parameter... not LOTS of. And `xargs` creates a lot of parameters.

To solve your real problem (only list the filenames):

```
 find . -name '*.deb' -printf "%f\n"
```

Which prints just the 'basename' (man find):

```
 %f     File's name with any leading directories
        removed (only the last element).
```

Comment: oooh.... */slaps forehead again/*  i think i need a "find for dummies" book...

Comment: i thought the point of `xargs` is that it creates a list of arguments and feeds each to the command that comes after? otherwise what's the difference between that and `find . -name '*.deb' | basename` ?

Comment: GNU basename now has a `-a` option: "support multiple arguments and treat each as a name".

Comment: @WindowsMaker `xargs` converts `stdin` to command arguments. In a way, it's the opposite of `echo`, which converts its arguments to `stdout`. The difference between `find ... | xargs -n1 basename` or `find ... | xargs basename -a` and `find ... | basename` is that the former two will work with implementations of `basename` that ignore `stdin`.

Comment: @WindowsMaker, if my understanding is that you use ```-I {}``` xargs option, like this  ```| xargs -I {} basename -s .json {} | ```, it will feed each argument separately

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
find . -name '*.deb' | xargs -n1 basename
```

Comment: this is not the explanation, this is a workaround. and the workaround is as good as just calling 'basename' via -exec for any file found.

Comment: +1 ... while not an explanation, this would lead me to investigate the xargs switch you show, which would eventually lead me to the forehead-slapping motion i just used reading akira's and john t's answers...

Comment: This is how I do it. I don't feel like learning all the ins and outs of the `find` command, so I only use it for finding and listing files, and I use xargs for everything else.

Answer (score 4):

basename only accepts a single argument. Using `-exec` works properly because each `{}` is replaced by the current filename being processed, and the command is run once **per matched file**, instead of trying to send all of the arguments to basename in one go.

Answer (score 4):

`xargs` can be forced to just pass one argument as well...

`find . -name '*.deb' -print | xargs -n1 basename`

This works, however the accepted answer is using `find` in a more appropriate way. I found this question searching for `xargs basename` problems as I'm using another command to get a list of file locations. The `-n1` flag for `xargs` was the ultimate answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that by default `xargs` does not use just one input item to build one command invocation.

In fact, `xargs` uses as many input items as possible every time it executes the command, where the max number of items used to build one command invocation is a system-defined value and can be overwritten by the `-n` or `-L` options. For example, if you run `echo a b | xargs ls`, instead of executing `ls` twice with `a` and `b` respectively, `xargs` will build and run a single command `ls a b`.

So for a command that accepts only one parameter (like `basename`), you should use the `-n` or `-L` option if you want to stick to `xargs`.